# Python/PyQt4: How do you find the SIZE of a monitor (in inches)?

Tags: python, screen, pyqt4, monitor, dpi

I'm trying to find the horizontal width of a monitor in inches or cm (not pixels!) to make a small "ruler" program. DPI would work too.

I'm using PyQt4.

Comment: What GUI framework are you using?

Comment: A Python 3 solution: `monitor_width_in_cm = input('Please enter the horizontal width of your monitor (in cm)')`

Comment: @Matthias nicely done! But seriously, this person needs to choose a GUI or graphical framework before we can help.

Comment: What we need is to know display density and display size (preferably in cm, although inches can be converted)

Comment: @ranmat11 I'm using PyQt4, I forgot to say that.

Answer (score 2):

try using the QDesktopWidget's width() and height() to get the width and height respectively.
Class reference at [QDesktopWidget Class Reference](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qdesktopwidget.html), this will give you the screens size in pixels and then use [QX11Info.appDpiX](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qx11info.html#appDpiX), this will give you the DPI in pixels per inch. Use both the above info to calculate the screen size in inches.

PS: The width() returns the union width, so in case you have multiple screens, it will return union width of all the screens.

Comment: I'm not looking for the width in pixels, I'm looking for the width in inches (as in, real world measurements). DPI would work too.