# How to calculate the dimensions of the monitor in PyQt4/Windows/Linux?

Tags: python

I'm trying to visualize portions of an image in my application with a fixed real dimension. For example 3x4cm. For now I'm supposing a fixed 96 DPI, but that's of course wrong!
I'm wondering if there is something like a DPI property in PyQt? I couldn't find it.
Currently I've tried on Windows but I want my application to work also on Linux so I would love an unified way of doing that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19070370/python-pyqt4-how-do-you-find-the-size-of-a-monitor-in-inches

Comment: thanks, my question seems like a duplicate!